# How do I configure the database using php_server module

Tags: 7, database

I am trying to set up an existing site locally. It seems that Drush cannot find the site. When I run `drush cc all`, I get this error.

> No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.

I think the issue may be with my server configuration. I am using the [PHP Server](https://www.drupal.org/project/php_server) module, and I'm not sure how to get it to point to the database.

This is what `drush status` returns, for your reference:

```
 Drupal version         :  7.41                                             
 Site URI               :  http://default                                   
 Database driver        :  mysql                                            
 Database hostname      :  localhost                                        
 Database username      :  root                                             
 Database name          :  quorum                                           
 PHP executable         :  /usr/local/bin/php                               
 PHP configuration      :  /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini                   
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin                                           
 Drush script           :  /usr/local/Cellar/drush/8.1.11/libexec/drush.php 
 Drush version          :  8.1.11                                           
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                             
 Drush configuration    :                                                   
 Drush alias files      :                                                   
 Drupal root            :  /Users/Jillian/ideometry/quorum-dev              
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php                       
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are running the drush command in directory where your project code doesn't exists. I think you are getting logged in to home directory of a server where the project code does not exists. Your project code is in another directory. for e.g

```
-opt
 -webcode
  -project_code
-home
-etc
```

So you are getting loggedin in the home directory but your code is inside /opt/webcode/project_code. You need to reach to project_code directory first and then run the drush command.

You can use filezilla if you are not aware of the directory stucture. It will help you to know which directory has your project code.